# Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp4 0.0.0.0:80: bind: address already in use

Tags: docker, ubuntu

I am trying  to follow a tutorial for Docker beginners (https://docs.docker.com/get-started/)

When I try to run this command:
`$ docker run -d -p 80:80 docker/getting-started`

I get this Error:

`docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint suspicious_murdock (863f389a032ea76d187c4387701b9eb0b6d4de4d0a9ed414616fa6b4715346ab): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp4 0.0.0.0:80: bind: address already in use.`

I tried removing all the dockers `docker rm -fv $(docker ps -aq)`  but it did nothing.

What can I do?

Comment: If you are running multiple dockerized services, you can easily mount the ports and use another port number: docker run -d -p 81:80 docker/getting-started

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Or you can use a different port like `docker run -d -p 8080:80 docker/getting-started`. This way you do not need to stop the apache2 running on the host.

Answer (score 28):

I had to stop apache2 from running on port :80 - `sudo service apache2 stop`

Comment: I had a similar issue however the service I left running on port 80 was not apache and was instead Nginx. to fix this I ran ```sudo systemctl stop nginx```

Comment: I had a similar problem when using haproxy via docker-compose. Stopping appache solved it.

Comment: To permanently disable Apache, so it won't start again on reboot, use `sudo update-rc.d apache2 disable`

Answer (score 15):

## why is this error showing?

This error means that you have a process *listening* to port 80 (the default HTTP port). This is probably a server of some sorts like apache/nginx/lighttpd.
Other answers suggest closing a database (mysql/mariadb), but - if configured correctly - they will be using a different port (most often 3306). This means that stopping your database will probably not solve the issue, since they are not using port 80.

## how to find out what is causing this?

from [here](https://www.tecmint.com/find-out-which-process-listening-on-a-particular-port/):
In a terminal type (with `sudo`, so it also shows root processes):

```
sudo lsof -i :80
```

you should get something like this:

```
COMMAND     PID       USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
lighttpd   1713   www-data    4u  IPv6  36989      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
lighttpd   1713   www-data    5u  IPv4  36990      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
firefox-b 23384  your-user  150u  IPv4 122957      0t0  TCP pop-os:37322->ef-in-f94.1e100.net:http (ESTABLISHED)
firefox-b 23384  your-user  174u  IPv4 122155      0t0  TCP pop-os:37314->ef-in-f94.1e100.net:http (ESTABLISHED)
```

Note the `(LISTEN)` vs `(ESTABLISHED)` at the end. `(LISTEN)` is the culprit here, caused by the command `lighttpd`, which is a server. Also, the `USER` of `lighttpd` is `www-data`, which is not you, so it would not show without `sudo`.

Now, to stop it, use:

```
sudo service stop lighttpd
```

where you replace `lighttpd` with whatever the command is (of course you kind of want to know what you're doing here, since you don't accidentally want to pull your website offline).

Comment: To permanently disable the service, so it won't start again on reboot, use `sudo update-rc.d lighttpd disable` (or whatever service it is)

Answer (score 5):

In case you change ports and still encounter the same problem especially on Ubuntu 18 try stopping your apache serve and mysql/mariadb port if you further encounter mysql/mariadb port already been used.
Try these two commands.

```
sudo service apache2 stop

sudo service mysql stop

sudo service mariadb stop
```

Answer (score 1):

Since it is *port 80* that is already in use the issue is most likely that you left a service such as an [Nginx](https://www.nginx.com/) or even [Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/) to fix this I would recommend first trying:

```
sudo systemctl stop nginx
```

If this fails then try:

```
sudo service apache2 stop
```

If either of these work then try running your docker container

Answer (score 0):

I had smiliar problem after removing my Jenkins images and containers for multimple times. Just by restarting the docker it works properly:

sudo systemctl restart docker

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, for the hints ...

same happen to me, was not able to install nginx-proxy-manager receiving error:
"Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp4 0.0.0.0:80: bind: address already in use"
First trying to find who uses the port 80 with "lsof -i :80" then using command: "systemctl stop nginx" and finally using the command "systemctl restart docker"
and bang the container stack will be created without error